# Scaling Android Apps up For Tablets

Tags: android, scaling, tablet, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I currently have an android application created using android 4.0. I originally developed it for a phone screen size but decided I wanted to try it out on my real life tablet. The problem is (which most of you probably already know) is that all the textviews and buttons remain small because it's ment for a phone. I was talking to a professor of mine and she had mentioned a one line piece of code that goes into the xml manifest which will automatically scale up everything for me. Searching around the only thing I found that seemed the simplest to implement was this:

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" />
```

When I added in this code it didn't see to make a difference. I even tried the xlragescreens just in case.

Am I doing something wrong or is there really an easy way to make my apps scale up easily or do i have to make a tablet version?

Also a few quick points that may help:
The tablet is: nexus 7 (running 4.1)
I do have the targetSdkVersion set at 15 (looking on the net I saw that you need to set it above 11 for scaling).

Thanks!

Comment: What did you use in your layout XML to define sizes?  Please show an example

Comment: @Simon I didn't define any sizes, I just used a relative view and just dragged and dropped the buttons. I can post the code if it would help but all it really is, is just the regular auto-generated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a /res/layout-large folder and name the XML file the same as the one you are already using in /res/layout.  This layout will then be used when loaded on large screens like tablets.  Also, it is best practice to use `match_parent` and `wrap_content` to size your UI elements and not define them using `px` or `dp`.

For more info on creating a UI for all displays go here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html